# I moved a chart to a seperate sheet, do I have to reference the original sheet in front of every cell reference?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

The name of the sheet I moved the chart from is `Systm`. Can I get rid of the redundancy?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(IF(({
 'Systm'!$K$294:$K$339, 'Systm'!$BE$294:$BE$339}= 4  )*({
 'Systm'!$L$294:$L$339, 'Systm'!$BF$294:$BF$339}= "" ), { 
 'Systm'!$J$294:$J$339, 'Systm'!$BD$294:$BD$339}     )))
```

Answer (score 0):

When a formula directly references a range that is in a tab that is different from the tab where the formula is, the reference will have to include the sheet name.

To refer to data using symbolic names, use [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), and to bind data to a function, use [lambda()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) to create a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), like this:

```
=let( 
  data, vstack(Systm!J294:L339, Systm!BD294:BF339), 
  col_, lambda(c, choosecols(data, c)), 
  matches, filter(col_(1), col_(2) = 4, col_(3) = ""), 
  count(matches)  
)
```